# Retrieve input type text box value at server side using request["id"] but could not find it

Tags: asp.net

I want to retrieve an input type text box value at server side using `request["id"]` but could not find it. That  text box is generated into an AJAX tab panel using `StringBuilder`, as follows:

```
sb1.Append("<input type=\"text\" value=\"0.00\" MaxLength=\"11\" onkeyup=\"DecimalNumber(this) \" onPaste=\"return false \" onFocus=\"javascript:ClearValue(this); \" onBlur=\" javascript:updateValue('" + tb.ID + "')\" onChange=\" javascript:updateValue('" + tb.ID + "','TabContainer1_tbpnlusrdetails_txtDeduct','TabContainer1_tbpnlusrdetails_txtt‌​otalAmount') \" name=\"TextBox_0039001010200-323-31 \" id=\"TextBox_0039001010200-323-31\" ");
```

Comment: sb1.Append("<input type=\"text\"  value=\"0.00\"  MaxLength=\"11\" onkeyup=\"DecimalNumber(this) \" onPaste=\"return false \" onFocus=\"javascript:ClearValue(this); \" onBlur=\" javascript:updateValue('" + tb.ID + "')\" onChange=\" javascript:updateValue('" + tb.ID + "','TabContainer1_tbpnlusrdetails_txtDeduct','TabContainer1_tbpnlusrdetails_txttotalAmount') \"  name=\"TextBox_0039001010200-323-31 \"  id=\"TextBox_0039001010200-323-31\" ");

Comment: how did you try to access it ? you should edit your question and add that too

Answer (score -1):

I thing you have to create the dynamic text box in PageLoad also to get the value.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
.....
        }
```